# What's the difference between Google Cloud SDK and App Engine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

They seem to do the same job but why are they separately listed?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Google Cloud SDK contains tools and libraries that enable you to
>   easily create and manage resources on Google Cloud Platform, including
>   App Engine, Compute Engine, Cloud Storage, BigQuery, Cloud SQL, and
>   Cloud DNS.
>
> Google Cloud SDK contains both the preview version of a new App
>   Engine's command-line tool gcloud preview app, and App Engine Java,
>   Python, PHP and Go SDKs.

So, the Cloud SDK is a wider set of tools that includes the App Engine SDK (for different run times) and much more.

Comment: It seems you can't deploy an app with the AppEngineSDK alone... which makes it utterly superfluous for most developers. Just get the Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: @RayFoss: You can deploy your app from Google Eclipse Plugin, which includes App Engine SDK.

Answer (score 0):

And for maven plugin, Google Cloud Platform provides guide to migrate from App Engine SDK plugin to Cloud SDK plugin:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-maven