# gcloud preview app deploy uploads all souce code files everytime in python project taking long time

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

After i recently updated the gcloud components with `gcloud components update` to version 108.0.0, i noticed the `gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml` command has started taking too long every time (about 15 minutes) for my project. Before this it only used to take about a minute to complete.

I figured out that using `gcloud preview app deploy --verbosity info app.yaml` displays progress of deployment process and I noticed every file in source code is being uploaded every time i deploy including the files in `lib` directory which has a number of packages installed, about 2000 files in it so this is where the delay is coming from. Since I am new to appengine, i dont know if this is normal.

The project exists inside a folder of git repo, and i noticed after every deploy, 2 files in `default` directory, `source-context.json` and `source-contexts.json`, are being created and have information about git repo inside. I feel that can somehow be relevant.

I went through a number of relevant questions here but couldnt figure out the issue. It would be great if this can be resolved if its an issue at all because its a big inconvenience having to wait 15 mins to deploy every time.

I only started using google appengine a month ago so please dont mind if the question is incorrect. Please let me know if additional info is needed to resolve this. Thanks

**UPDATE:** I am using gcloud sdk on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Do you have a new version at each deploy?  Or are you reusing the same version?  If you reuse a version, I believe only changed files are uploaded but if you change the version, all files are uploaded.

Comment: Although i like the idea, what if something in the new deploy crashes and i need to rollback to previous deploy? I wont have a version to rollback to right? If this is not the case and your suggestion works then this is the correct answer. I will give an update after i confirm this. Till now i have not been mentioning `--version` in deploy command in which case gcloud creates a version automatically.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill i pass a fixed `--version`, and `gcloud app deploy` sometimes only uploads changed files, but sometimes uploads all of them. not sure why yet. (gcloud sdk 182.0.0, app-engine-python 1.9.63, on mac os x.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the expected behaviour, each deployment is standalone, no assumption is made about anything being "already deployed", all app's artifacts are uploaded  at every deployment.

**Update**: Kekito's comment suggests different tools may actually behave differently. My answer applies to the linux version of the Python SDK, regardless of deploying a new version or re-deploying the same version.

Comment: oh. but it wasnt like this before i updated the gcloud version?

Comment: I has always been like that AFAIK. Something *else* might have changed, it coulod be some transient condition. Re-try a few times to make sure it's not a transient. If it's not then rollback to the previous version you had, to see if it's indeed related to the upgrade.

Comment: When i deployed new versions to the project before, it took only a minute, now its 15 to 20 mins. I have tried to rollback previous version but no luck. Also retried deploying several times. Thanks, i will keep looking to find out the reason. Will accept the answer once i solve why it was so fast before.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk/33770297#33770297, it offers an alternative you *might* find acceptable.

Comment: I use the AppEngineLauncher GUI to deploy, and it only uploads files that have changed.  You see log statements like this: `10:41 AM Uploaded 2 files and blobs.`

Comment: I commonly deploy changes and see only 2 files uploaded. Occasionally hundreds, though, although only one or two have changed. It seems to be a function of either a `git commit` changing the file access times or the elapsed time since the last deployment.