# google api client python import taskqueue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip, google-cloud-sdk

python version `2.7.9`

installed version `1.5.1`

`pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks) trying to import task queue like so

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
```

getting

```
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.api
```

1.5.1 is the latest version, and I can't seem to find any code reference to task queue in the pip code [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client)

Comment: What SDK version? This *might* be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755195/importerror-no-module-named-webapp2-after-linux-sdk-upgrade-1-9-35-1-9-38

Comment: gcloud SDK ? Google Cloud SDK 112.0.0

Comment: Hm, I'm only using the GAE SDK, I'm not sure about the version mapping to the cloud SDK...

Comment: upgraded to 120.0.0 and still the same error

Comment: this *might* be something to consider as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk

Comment: Can you add an MCV (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example? Or some description of your app's structure, libs, from which file your're trying the import, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the sdk from here
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

after downloaded added it to my project source files .

and added the path to the home directory in my python code like so

```
import os, sys

test_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
paths = [
    '/../../google_appengine',
]

for path in paths:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(test_directory + path))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Cloud SDK - Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes) tracks the version of the GAE components, search for the `App Engine components updated to` pattern.

The version of the most recent GAE components in the current Cloud SDK version (120.0.0) is 1.9.38 (emphasis mine):

> Google App Engine
>
> ...
>
> - Google App Engine components updated to **1.9.38**.

The 1.9.38 version is affected by a bug causing import errors, see ["ImportError: No module named webapp2" after Linux SDK upgrade (1.9.35 -> 1.9.38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755195/importerror-no-module-named-webapp2-after-linux-sdk-upgrade-1-9-35-1-9-38)

I see 2 options for you:

- downgrade to a Cloud SDK version prior to **109.0.0** (in which the affected GAE version 1.9.37 was introduced)
- if you only use GAE and not other Cloud products for which you **need** the Cloud SDK switch to the GAE SDK (current version 1.9.40 in which the issue is fixed), see the comments to this Q&A: [What is the relationship between Google's App Engine SDK and Cloud SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk)

Comment: downgraded to 108.0.0 . `gcloud components update --version 108.0.0                                                                     
Your current Cloud SDK version is: 109.0.0
You will be upgraded to version: 108.0.0` . still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this question is still open and instead of the above I might try `from google.appengine.api.taskqueue import taskqueue` I looked at the source and a few other docs and I see the same pattern used in the Class