# GAE not finding httplib2

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, httplib2

I'm trying to run the sample code
https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/appengine
 from the Google API Python Client on the Google Cloud platform. After starting the test app I'm seeing this error:

```
ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

I checked the cloud env provided and it has the lib available

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

/google/go_appengine/lib/httplib2
/google/go_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2
/google/google_appengine/lib/httplib2
/google/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/lib/third_party/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python3/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bq/third_party/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2
/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python3/httplib2
/home/MY_USER/src/triple-carrier-142807/python_gae_quickstart-2016-09-08-10-47/httplib2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2
```

I can import it in the python command line:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib2
>>>
```

It must be installed but GAE is not recognizing it.

Comment: Did you ran this python shell with active env?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The GAE was active with the above deployment which isn't working. I ran the "dev_appserver.py $PWD" command and opened the URL just to test it.

Comment: potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848896/google-api-client-python-import-taskqueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it myself by putting httplib2 in the engine dir (the dir where app.yaml exists).

Comment: That's not a very good idea - that httplib2 code will be deployed to GAE as part as your app and - if executed instead of GAE's httplib2 - your app will likely not work.

Comment: Please elaborate on what could not work? I did the same with the googleapiclient lib and got this error:  File "/home/v_stariradev/src/triple-carrier-142807/google-api-python-client-vladi/appengine/googleapiclient/discovery.py"
, line 20, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six

Comment: GAE-provided libs are specially customized for the GAE environment. You can't just use your own lib (or the GAE local development lib) instead, which you'd effectively be attempting by copying/linking the local httplib2 into your app dir. BTW, what I'm referring to is potential problems when deployed on GAE, not on your development server (the `six` error is unrelated to this - there are threads on it on SO).

Comment: httplib2 isn't one of the appengine-provided libraries Including it in your project is the correct thing to do.