# How to import google's taskqueue library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, task-queue, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to use google task queues in `python3`, but I am facing some trouble while importing `taskqueue` library. On issuing the following command

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'
```

I have installed [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb) and additionally installed 2 more packages as mentioned in the link.

> google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python
>
> google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python-extras

I have checked the version of `gcloud` components that has been installed

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 206.0.0
alpha 2018.06.18
app-engine-python 1.9.70
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.70
beta 2018.06.18
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.06.18
gsutil 4.32
```

Why I cannot be able to import taskqueue, Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google api client python import taskqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848896/google-api-client-python-import-taskqueue)

Comment: Are you doing this within an app engine application?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I just try running it from terminal

Comment: I think it needs to run as part of an app engine application - I don't think task queues exist as stand-alone services.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Can you refer any task queue tutorial for beginners, there are very limited resource available to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Task Queue service has limited availability outside of the [App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#task_queue). This issue was reported [at](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3834), please deploy an App Engine standard app to test this out. You can find sample code [at](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/multitenancy/taskqueue.py).