# `gcloud app deploy` vs. `appcfg.py`

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I've been a long time user of **appcfg.py** and I even build some bash scripts on top of it.

1. Should we switch to **gcloud app deploy**? Will **appcfg.py** be deprecated? If yes what is the timeline?
2. Why isn't there a grace period for backward compatibility of the yaml file? Switching to **gcloud app deploy** I get:

> The [application] field is specified in file [.../app.yaml]. This
>   field is not used by gcloud and must be removed. Project name should
>   instead be specified either by `gcloud config set project MY_PROJECT`
>   or by setting the `--project` flag on individual command executions.

and

> ERROR: The [version] field is specified in file [.../app.yaml]. This
>   field is not used by gcloud and must be removed. Versions are
>   generated automatically by default but can also be manually specified
>   by setting the `--version` flag on individual command executions.

I am saying this as this was possible w/ the module/service field:

> WARNING: The "module" parameter in application .yaml files is
>   deprecated. Please use the "service" parameter instead.

3. How do you upload **queue.yaml**, **dispatch.yaml** and **cron.yaml** with **gcloud app deploy**?
4. What are the differences between the 2 ways of deploying an app?

   I'm interested in caveats & things to watch for like:

> FLAGS --promote Promote the deployed version to receive all traffic. True by default.

That means w/ **gcloud app deploy** the app will be deployed and the new version will be set as the active one... this is exactly the reverse way **appcfg.py** did things as there you would have to call **set_default_version** to mark a version as active.

This raises my last question: if I opt to NOT make it active by using either

> $ gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false

or

> Use --no-promote to disable.

will I have to redeploy w/ default value so I can make it active?

Comment: a bit too many questions for a single post IMHO. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Long story short:

1. `gcloud app deploy` is going to be the preferred path for deployments going forward, and is currently supported. You'll have about a year after we declare deprecation to transition.
2. Before we deprecate `appcfg.py`, we'll have a full migration guide with all of the changes. We don't *want* full backwards compatibility, because we're seizing this chance to fix some warts with the old tooling.
3. You can run `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml` and so on to deploy the alternate YAML files.
4. Again, we're planning on writing a migration guide before we want to force you over to the new tooling.

So I think you can punt on this until we've officially deprecated the `appcfg` tooling–`gcloud app` is really meant for brave explorers who want the newest and shiniest for now.

Comment: One of the flags I regularly use in appcfg is the -A to deploy the same code base to multiple projects, e.g. dev/test/live projects... How do I do that with gcloud app deploy? There isn't a -A flag in the docs.

Comment: You're looking for `--project`

Comment: Also you should look at `gcloud config configurations list`

Comment: @ZacharyNewman it appears to me that you have to have 'Project Editor' permissions in order to run `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml'.  I've tried 'App Engine Admin, Deployer etc' but always get a 403 error. What permissions are necessary when deploying configuration files: queue.yaml and cron.yaml? I have seen the new Datastore Index Admin, so have no issue deploying index.yaml.

Comment: Deploying cron.yaml currently hits the same API as appcfg.py used to, so the same permissions are necessary (and the old API was published *before* roles besides Editor/Owner/Viewer existed). If you have follow-up questions, please start a new thread.

Comment: How do we set environment variables using gcloud app deploy ?