# What is the equivalent of `appcfg.py -E` in `gcloud app deploy`?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35410433/260805) answer says that `appcfg.py -E` allows me to set secrets on deploy and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280666/gcloud-app-deploy-vs-appcfg-py) answer says that `appcfg.py` will go away. Is there a way for me to set environment variables on command line when deploying an AppEngine app using `gcloud app deploy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't for deployments. Instead, you can always specify your environment variables [in the app.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I edited the answer. Basically, you can't, according to the documentation. This is the option to follow in deployments.