# PyCharm - Can't create App Engine Application using DJango

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, pycharm

The last few days I tried to create an App Engine Application based on DJango using PyCharm Professional 2016.3.2..

But everytime I try to create a new App Engine Application using Django as an third-party library PyCharm throws an Error and tells 'Create App Engine Application - Incorrect or corrupted App Engine SKD: cannot finde DJango installation'.

I already tried to install everything again, including Python, PyCharm, Django and the SDK, but it still doesn't work.

I would really appreciate any kind of help, because this problem drives me crazy.

Comment: which SDK are you using - the old AppEngine SDK or the Cloud SDK?

Comment: The Google Cloud SDK Version 138.0.0

Comment: I can't find it explicitly stated in the docs, but I think with the cloud sdk you need to pip install django yourself, using [Google's vendoring instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) - it isn't bundled with the cloud sdk like in the old sdk.

Comment: Yes, the cloud SDK's app-engine-python (1.9.49) is missing several GAE-provided libs which are present in the GAE SDK: all `django` versions, as well as `graphy`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install extras.

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python-extras
```

And then try to create django (app engine) project again.

Answer (score 1):

The legacy Appengine SDK ships with some Django versions included in its `lib` folder.

```
$  find 1.9.40/ -type d -name [Dd]jango*
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/examples/rwbench/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/ext/django2jinja
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.4
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.4/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/PyAMF-0.6.1/pyamf/tests/adapters/django_app
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.2
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.2/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/PyAMF-0.7.2/pyamf/adapters/tests/django_app
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-0.96
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-0.96/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.9
1.9.40/google_appengine/lib/django-1.9/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/django
1.9.40/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/builtins/django_wsgi
1.9.40/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/django
```

However the Google Cloud SDK does not include any Django versions in `lib`, only with Django utilities for its own internal use.

```
$  gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 138.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.49
...

$  find google-cloud-sdk/ -type d -name [Dd]jango*
google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/oauth2client/contrib/django_util
google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/appengine/ext/builtins/django_wsgi
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/examples/rwbench/django
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/ext/django2jinja
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/PyAMF-0.6.1/pyamf/tests/adapters/django_app
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/PyAMF-0.7.2/pyamf/adapters/tests/django_app
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/django
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/builtins/django_wsgi
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/django
google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/contrib/django_util
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/appengine/ext/builtins/django_wsgi
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/examples/rwbench/django
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/ext/django2jinja
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/lib/PyAMF-0.6.1/pyamf/tests/adapters/django_app
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/lib/PyAMF-0.7.2/pyamf/adapters/tests/django_app
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/_internal/django
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/django
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/builtins/django_wsgi
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/django
google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/contrib/django_util
```

The solution is to install Django according to Google's instructions for installing third party packages, that is:

1. Install django in your third party libs folder:`pip install django -t lib`
2. Add `from google.appengine.ext import vendor;vendor.add('lib')` in your `appengine_config.py` module

Answer (score 1):

As @snakecharmerb observed the django packages are missing in the `app-engine-python` component (1.9.49) of the cloud SDK (138.0.0).

They are, however, present in the standalone GAE SDK (also 1.9.49):

```
/usr/local # diff google_appengine_1.9.49/lib google-cloud-sdk-138.0.0/platform/google_appengine/lib | grep -vi common
Only in google_appengine_1.9.49/lib: django-0.96
Only in google_appengine_1.9.49/lib: django-1.2
Only in google_appengine_1.9.49/lib: django-1.3
Only in google_appengine_1.9.49/lib: django-1.4
Only in google_appengine_1.9.49/lib: django-1.5
Only in google_appengine_1.9.49/lib: django-1.9
Only in google_appengine_1.9.49/lib: graphy
```

So an alternative to vendoring django into your app **might** be to switch to this SDK instead of the cloud SDK. See [What is the relationship between Google's App Engine SDK and Cloud SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk/33770297#33770297), including comments.

Note that it's not the recommended way these days, tho.

You *could* also install both and try to copy/symlink the missing packages into the cloud SDK. YMMV.

To download the GAE SDK in the [Download the SDK for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/download#python_linux) page click on the [Optionally, you can also download the original App Engine SDK for Python.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/download#python_linux) "link" - it's actually a control for the expandable download section below:

[image]