# Is it necessary to install the App Engine extension for Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I have an App Engine application in Python. I can deploy it simply by installing and initializing the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). But according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/):

> The default installation does not include the App Engine extensions required to deploy an application using `gcloud` commands. These components can be installed using the [Cloud SDK component manager](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/managing-components).

It also mentioned in [Download the SDK for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download): I just took the second step and then deployed my app.

Answer (score 1):

The extension applies only to the Cloud SDK and would be needed only if you're using the Cloud SDK, if the extension is actually needed for the particular operation you're executing and if the extension is not already installed.

It is unrelated to (and thus not needed for) the GAE SDK, which is complete/monolithic.

See also [What is the relationship between Google's App Engine SDK and Cloud SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk/33770297#33770297)

Comment: "The extension applies only to the Cloud SDK" I'm using the _Cloud SDK_. "if the extension is actually needed" It's needed according to the documentation, but I deploy my apps without the extension. "if the extension is not already installed" It's not installed.

Comment: They may have moved some of the pieces common to all GAE language packages in the core or some other package installed by default. But you *might* not be able to do other stuff (like running your app locally, for example). It's not uncommon for the docs to lag behind the actual functionality.