# deploy scala sbt to google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

While importing my scala sbt project to intellij i get the following error

```
Error while importing SBT project: ... 
[info] Loading project definition from /home/dnilesh/Desktop/app-engine/sbt-appengine-demo-master/project
java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set APPENGINE_SDK_HOME
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at sbtappengine.Plugin$AppEngine$.buildAppengineSdkPath(AppenginePlugin.scala:103)
at sbtappengine.Plugin$$anonfun$baseAppengineSettings$33.apply(AppenginePlugin.scala:219)
at sbtappengine.Plugin$$anonfun$baseAppengineSettings$33.apply(AppenginePlugin.scala:219)
at sbt.Init$Value$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Settings.scala:604)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$constant$1.apply(INode.scala:163)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$constant$1.apply(INode.scala:163)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] You need to set APPENGINE_SDK_HOME
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Invalid response.
 See complete log in file:/home/dnilesh/.IdeaIC2017.2/system/log/sbt.last.log  Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

and while deploying same app to google app engine from terminal i get the same error after that, In terminal i set APPENGINE_SDK_HOME to my google cloud installation directory `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/`. then i get the following error.

So how can i set APPENGINE_SDK_HOME and to which path so that `sbt appengineDeploy` command will work.

```
root@dnilesh-pc:/home/dnilesh/Desktop/app-engine/sbt-appengine-demo-master# sbt appengineDeploy
[info] Loading project definition from /home/dnilesh/Desktop/app-engine/sbt-appengine-demo-master/project
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found appengine api jar.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbtappengine.Plugin$AppEngine$.buildSdkVersion(AppenginePlugin.scala:114)
    at sbtappengine.Plugin$$anonfun$baseAppengineSettings$32.apply(AppenginePlugin.scala:218)
    at sbtappengine.Plugin$$anonfun$baseAppengineSettings$32.apply(AppenginePlugin.scala:218)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
    at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] not found appengine api jar.
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Comment: what will be path for APPENGINE_SDK_HOME or how can i set it.  https://github.com/jasonmar/sbt-appengine-demo#setup

Comment: `APPENGINE_SDK_HOME` *might* be referring to the GAE SDK, not the GCloud one, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk/33770297#33770297. Check if it's the case and, if so, install the GAE SDK as well. At least on Linux both SDKs can coexist on the same system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps I did to sort out this issue:

1. Download the App Engine SDK for Java:
   [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download)

[Direct Download Link](https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54.zip)

2. Extract it in your computer regardless your GCloud installed path.
3. set APPENGINE_SDK_HOME :

   export APPENGINE_SDK_HOME= /PATH/TO/SDK/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54
4. Download Sample Scala sbt application.
   [Github Sample Scala App](https://github.com/jasonmar/sbt-appengine-demo)
5. run `sbt appengineDeploy` command to run app. change project id to your project id on google cloud. [Steps before running app](https://github.com/jasonmar/sbt-appengine-demo#google-app-engine-basics)

Notes:

1. You cannot install third party databases like mongodb on gae.
2. gae does not support akka framework.
3. gae does not support multithreading.

Comment: Is it possible to use akka framework in APP engine flexible mode ?

Comment: @RumeshKrishnan yes, you can run stateless web app you want on App Engine flexible environment since it runs a Docker container for you, and you can put whatever you want in that container for the most part.