# Total confusion about which path to use for GoLang AppEngine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm having trouble referencing the AppEngine SDK.

After installing Google Cloud SDK, I'm using:

```
gcloud components install app-engine-go
```

to install the most recent version of the AppEngine SDK for Go, and afterwards I'm seeing 2 directories:

`/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk
/Users/kieran/google-cloud-sdk`

The first contains the AppEngine SDK files, the second does not.

In the PATH I'm seeing:

`# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f ‘/Users/kieran/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then source '/Users/kieran/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi`

`# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/kieran/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then source '/Users/kieran/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi`

Why is the gcloud installer adding a reference in the PATH to the google-cloud-sdk that does not contain the AppEngine SDK ?

I have read many different articles on here but they all mention a manually downloaded AppEngine SDK, and according to other articles even using "google.golang.org/appengine" is not good enough as it's not always the latest version.

How do I reference the AppEngine SDK that was downloaded by the glcoud installer? With 2 different SDK paths I'm totally confused about which one to use, and even how to reference it in code. I would assume that "appengine" would be sufficient, but that isn't working.

Comment: Side note: GAE SDK != GCloud SDK, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk/33770297#33770297.

Comment: By `AppEngine SDK` do you actually mean the GAE SDK (see comment above) or the GCloud SDK's `app-engine-go` component?

Comment: I realise they are not the same. I first installed the GCloud SDK, and then installed the `app-engine-go` component, which is the one I'm trying to understand, as it apparently installs the `app-engine-go` component under `/usr/local/google-gcloud-sdk` and NOT under `/Users/kieran/google-cloud-sdk` which is what GCloud SDK has added to the PATH.

Comment: You *might* have 2 SDKs installed, in different paths. Check `which gcloud` to see which one were you actually using.