# google app engine python flask built-in library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python, app.yaml

According to the [getting started](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) doc and the [built-in third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27). You should be able to add flask to your project using libraries in your app.yaml.

> Although Flask is bundled into the runtime, and could be used simply by adding in the app.yaml file's libraries: directive, this tutorial puts a copy of the library in your the app's directory, which demonstrates how you would include an unbundled third-party library so that your app can use it.

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: flask
  version: "latest"
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

However, I keep getting:

> ImportError: No module named flask

Has anyone been able to get this to work? Is there something I'm missing? I'm using the Cloud SDK for local development on Linux.

Comment: FWIW, your example works just fine for me - linux GAE SDK 1.9.61. Just one note: the indentation of your app.yaml file is not displayed OK - I'll edit your post to correct that - check if the actual indentation in the file is ok or not as it *might* have something to do with the error.

Comment: The website makes it seem that the GAE SDK is more legacy for people needing 'appcfg' command. If I have to use that it would defeat my purpose I can also use the third party method that is not for built-in libraries, but neither one is ideal. I'd like to use the recommended software with built-in library that the docs indicate should work.

Comment: That's debatable - I'm still happier with it than with the cloud SDK. Regardless - the cloud SDK is theoretically packing the same core as the individual GAE SDK(s) inside their respective language components - they even use the same version #s). But yes, occasionally there are divergences in functionality which can be addressed by switching between SDKs - which is why I have both installed :) Older, but still applicable in some regards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769879/what-is-the-relationship-between-googles-app-engine-sdk-and-cloud-sdk/33770297#33770297

Comment: It sounds like you have the Cloud SDK installed, if you run `gcloud components install app-engine-python` does the module not found error go away? (assuming you haven't mapped a local lib folder)

Comment: sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python yields sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python

Comment: @DanCornilescu I agree that the GAE SDK is more more suitable than the Cloud SDK. Sometimes you only need a banana instead of the whole jungle...

Answer (score 0):

You must also install in the `lib` folder in your project root:

`pip install flask -t lib/`

I guarantee you this will work